# Analytic continuation of $\sum z^n/n$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-continuation

I have the following function

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}z^n$$

It is easy to see that it converges for $|z|<1$ (root test, for example).

How can it be analytically continuated beyond the unit circle?

The usual trick of relating it to a geometric series doesn't seem to work.

Any idea or hint would be appreaciated!

Comment: Do you get something familiar, when you differentite $f(z)$? Can be done termwise in a set where the derivative converges uniformly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By integrating the geometric series term by term, you can easily obtain:

$$f(z) = -\log(1-z)$$

However, if you cannot sum a series into a closed form expression, you can sometimes still analytically continue the series to another series with a larger radius of convergence. E.g. if you substitute $z = \frac{w}{2-w}$ and re-expand in powers of $w$, what is then the radius of convergence in the $w$-plane and how does this region map back to the $z$-plane?

Comment: I don't get your $z = w / (2-w)$ idea. I think we still need to differentiate for showing something like  $f(1-xy) = f(1-x)+f(1-y)$

Comment: @arctictern Yes, I added "sometimes" to make clear that it won't always work.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, but suppose that you have no clue about the function. Also the series can be resummed this way term by term without even knowing the general nth term.